# How to convert the following TypeScript logic into a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, react-typescript

So, I initially wanted to do the following conversion:

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import { Component1, Component2 } from './components';

const components = {
  foo: Component1,
  bar: Component2,
};

// Into

const componentLookup = {
  foo: {
    name: 'foo',
    component: Component1
  },
  bar: {
    name: 'bar',
    component: Component2
  },
};
```

So, I created the following TS logic:

```
const components = {
  foo: Component1,
  bar: Component2,
};

type ComponentName = keyof typeof components;
type ComponentLookup = {
  [key in ComponentName]: {
    name: ComponentName;
    component: ComponentType;
  };
};

let componentLookup: ComponentLookup = {} as ComponentLookup;
(Object.keys(components) as ComponentName[]).forEach((name) => {
  componentLookup[name] = { name: name, component: components[name] };
});

// Intellisense picks up keys
componentLookup.foo;
componentLookup.bar;
```

Finally, I decided I want to create a function `createLookups` to take the components object and perform the logic instead, however, intellisense is having trouble.

```
const createLookups = (components: {
  [name: string]: ComponentType;
}): {
  [key in keyof typeof components]: {
    name: keyof typeof components;
    component: ComponentType;
  };
} => {
  type ComponentName = keyof typeof components;
  type ComponentLookup = {
    [key in ComponentName]: {
      name: ComponentName;
      component: ComponentType;
    };
  };

  let componentLookup: ComponentLookup = {} as ComponentLookup;
  (Object.keys(components) as ComponentName[]).forEach((name) => {
    componentLookup[name] = { name: name, component: components[name] };
  });

  return componentLookup;
};
```

If `createLookups` is defined in the same file and I call `createLookups(components)`, intellisense picks up on `foo` and `bar`; however, if `createLookups` is defined in another file, it does not pick up on the `foo`/`bar` keys readily.

Is this an issue with TypeScript or my editor (WebStorm)?

Comment: You should probably move the types outside the function.

Comment: @youdateme "_You should probably move the types outside the function_": No, that would create a compiler error as the data value form which the types are derived is a parameter of the function, which doesn't exist outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solve this problem in a general way (map the entries (key-value pairs) of an object to arbitrary property names), then you can apply it to your specific need (mapping property names and Component values), using a combination of [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314/438273) and [generic parameter constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbxgTzAUzgYQuCA7NPGAFVTQF84AzKHOAcijQEMBjGegbgChuV04AWWZh0AEwCiRKMDQBnADzc4cAPIAjAFZp2pAWgAeMQmLlwASjuhiFcmDLwBzADRwArngDWeCAHc8AHzOynAA0mjIAAq0YHCGxnimcHYOLiEAaswANm5o0RCx8SZmKcBOwQFwALyIIQDaoXBlcJ4REFRqWjokZAC6AFxwABQhKpas1grhUTGuoQGjcABkFlZQNpk5ebOd2rpkDb0LKgCUPOQ83FQe7MD4cCAiUvaycsQQ03IAkngaezBmJQqP7dPQYIqJMzjSalcruLw+fxBELTfKFIzFZIvcoZbK5NFxDGQrGpCpDCBaQYg-boVytGYFQaonYANzx20ZcE2+JiJ0GwlEaEk0leCmpPVpYQiaNc3I5YEqCBCTBgbigeGG4oAdPS5OStCc4MwzEN6e1dqCyCc6r0TlqmGI3Kw0EMho9BWI6RFDVVFYt3eI6vTetVaipw3Ag9KYgMWhFghGVHU2Vs0bGKZoo8hegnw5RjasJusptGCl7kObxWDKitocW5TKLTS0FnK11m0ceBGVWqNQGhV24ORXAh82YBeJnjJ5GL2xK0HNS2BZey0QEztxyLwAPTbuAAGTQHDMxjsTRg-V4EzwZ-7YlD7qnr3enx+4r1CCowCgdkGAEZXCyY0LzgAAmYcGDwZgQDQehXHoCZcAIIh6A3O8tS-H8YC1KCYM4OBdzgAAiTC7CI7h0NI7DEMgZCYHwwi8DcEB1DQKAKJEcQtSAuwcOgtAGL3IieJgcj0JErUaPwQh6IIvcmJYtidz3fcIAgTwzEcNSxGUuAADk-CNUQsmQc84BgCA4ArNVqBuGA7jwS9rzPVgmGYYxVPUtwwDMGoFGIQkEiSOsbFhFwsBwWiZOrAIhikui5EGYgfT9FQe3VB4nhFeQXwib5fjnPV4pkuR4Nw2D4OKlCNwubggA)

```ts
import {type ComponentType} from 'react';

type MappedEntries<
  ObjectType extends Record<string, unknown>,
  KeyProp extends string,
  ValueProp extends string,
> = {
  [K in keyof ObjectType]: (
    Record<KeyProp, K>
    & Record<ValueProp, ObjectType[K]>
  );
};

function mapEntriesToKeysInObjects <
  ObjectType extends Record<string, unknown>,
  KeyProp extends string,
  ValueProp extends string,
>(obj: ObjectType, keyProp: KeyProp, valueProp: ValueProp): MappedEntries<ObjectType, KeyProp, ValueProp> {
  return (Object.keys(obj) as (keyof ObjectType)[]).reduce((mapped, key) => {
    mapped[key] = {
      [keyProp]: key,
      [valueProp]: obj[key],
    } as Record<KeyProp, keyof ObjectType> & Record<ValueProp, ObjectType[keyof ObjectType]>;
    return mapped;
  }, {} as MappedEntries<ObjectType, KeyProp, ValueProp>);
}

// Let's test it:

const mapped = mapEntriesToKeysInObjects({first: 1, last: 2}, 'name', 'component');
mapped.first.name; // "first"
mapped.first.component; // number
mapped.last.name; // "last"
mapped.last.component; // number

// Looks good

// Now apply it to your function:
const createLookups = <T extends Record<string, ComponentType>>(components: T) => {
  return mapEntriesToKeysInObjects(components, 'name', 'component');
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Lot more TS knowledge in your solution I need to familiarize myself with. Is there any specific issue with my solution? Since I am still confused why keys are only being picked up when the function is defined in the same file.

Comment: @fihekil740 I can't speak to your experience — especially in regard to WebStorm as I don't have experience with it. The [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) is the de facto reproduction environment for type exploration, code problem diagnosis, demonstrating TS language features, examining compiler behavior, etc. I know for sure that [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) includes the exact same language server used by the TS playground.